# Coins displaying as popsicles?

Tags: temple-run-2

All of my Temple Run coins are being displaying as little popsicles. Is this a bug in the game? Should I reinstall Temple Run? I just don't want to lose all of my progress.

[image]

Comment: Have you connected the game to Game Center (iOS) or Play Store (Android)? If so, your progress will be saved and restored if you reinstall the game.

Comment: My guess is that it is some sort of summer themed update or something, but I don't play the game myself.

Answer (score 4):

It is a themed update for the summer. They regularly change the standard coins to other shapes in Temple Run 2 for special occasions, for example ghosts for Halloween or shamrocks for St Patrick's Day.

Answer (score 2):

Coin skins can be changed at the main menu screen [image]